# Explaining the code to check for CSS.supports() before using it

Tags: javascript, css

I've been seeing this piece of code recommended for checking for `CSS.supports()` support before using it:

```
var supportsCSS = !!((window.CSS && window.CSS.supports) || window.supportsCSS || false);
```

I understand everything about it, except the need for the `|| false` part. Can someone please explain that?

**EDIT:**

Sources:

https://davidwalsh.name/css-supports

https://medium.com/@barvysta/css-support-directive-and-its-js-twin-ready-to-use-6eea2fefef36

And those are not the only ones. It's quite spread.

Comment: Where did you see the code? `|| false` seems unnecessary...

Comment: It indeed does. The double negation (`!!`) already casts the value to a boolean.

Comment: I've added sources.

Comment: @Hlsg it seems to me that somebody wrote this (badly), and then everyone else just went ahead and copied it.

Comment: The legendary Cast-to-bool operator lives forever!

Comment: @skeborn indeed, but david walsh doesn't seem like a likely culprit, hence my cunundrum

Answer (score 0):

```
var supportsCSS = !!((window.CSS && window.CSS.supports) || window.supportsCSS || false);
```

I think "false" means not zero but "else".

*window.CSS.supports* is **current** syntax and *window.supportsCSS* is **old** syntax.

I mean "false" can be replaced with *"window.CSS.require_supports"* in the future.

!! is used to emphasise the code I think.